# Stuck at auto miner for Minecraft

Tags: python, minecraft

So the idea is that when you run the program and it will Strip Mine for you.

It has a toggle key and asks the user how many blocks forward they want to mine and what pick axe they are using to determine how long the program need to run.

I am just very stuck on getting the user input to work on registering the input for blocks you want to mine and what pick axe is being used.

Minecraft version 1.20.1
here is my code so far:

```
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter
import pyautogui
import keyboard

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode('dark')
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")

PICKAXE_TIMES = {
    "Wood Pick": 3,
    "Stone Pick": 3,
    "Iron Pick": 2,
    "Gold Pick": 2,
    "Diamond Pick": 2,
    "Nether Pick": 2
}

class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.is_auto_miner_active = False
        self.toggle_key = 'G'

        # config window
        self.title("Auto Miner Tool")
        self.geometry("300x300")

        # config toggle button
        self.on_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self, corner_radius=10, text=f"Toggle ({self.toggle_key})", command=self.toggle_auto_miner)
        self.on_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)

        # config change toggle key
        self.change_key_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self, corner_radius=10, text="Change Key Bind", command=self.change_key_bind)
        self.change_key_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.7, anchor=tk.CENTER)

        # config block entry
        self.block_entry_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self, text="Number of Blocks:")
        self.block_entry_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.block_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=self)
        self.block_entry.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.4, anchor=tk.CENTER)

        # config pickaxe selection
        self.pickaxe_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self, text="Select Pickaxe:")
        self.pickaxe_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.pickaxe_var = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.pickaxe_var.set("Wood Pick")  # Default selection
        self.pickaxe_dropdown = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(master=self, options=list(PICKAXE_TIMES.keys()), variable=self.pickaxe_var)
        self.pickaxe_dropdown.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.2, anchor=tk.CENTER)

        self.check_key_press()

    def toggle_auto_miner(self):
        if self.is_auto_miner_active:
            pyautogui.mouseUp(button='left')
            keyboard.release('w')
            self.is_auto_miner_active = False
        else:
            blocks_to_mine = int(self.block_entry.get())
            pickaxe = self.pickaxe_var.get()

            mining_time = PICKAXE_TIMES[pickaxe] * 2  # Assuming 2 seconds per block
            total_mining_time = mining_time * blocks_to_mine

            pyautogui.mouseDown(button='left')
            keyboard.press('w')
            self.is_auto_miner_active = True

            # Stop mining after the calculated time
            self.after(total_mining_time * 1000, self.stop_auto_miner)

    def stop_auto_miner(self):
        pyautogui.mouseUp(button='left')
        keyboard.release('w')
        self.is_auto_miner_active = False

    def change_key_bind(self):
        dialog = customtkinter.CTkInputDialog(text="Enter new key bind:", title="Change Key Bind")
        new_key = dialog.get_input()
        if new_key:
            self.toggle_key = new_key.upper()
            self.on_button.configure(text=f"Toggle ({self.toggle_key})")

    def check_key_press(self):
        if keyboard.is_pressed(self.toggle_key):
            self.toggle_auto_miner()
        self.after(10, self.check_key_press)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

I tried messing with the times but other than that I am lost so far...

any help towards this would be very appreciated as I am learning!

Comment: How I can approach this fixing/ getting the time to mine blocks to work

Comment: To be on-topic here, a question needs to be about a narrow, specific technical problem. Not knowing what to write next is not a narrow, specific issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I have edited your question and title to make it easier to read, no worries, others will understand your question(s). Read [ask] and [example], actually you posted an example but haven't added a specific question about your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `input()` built-in function in Python it basically asks user for input on the Command-line / Terminal for the user. For example you could do:

```
num_of_blocks = input("How many blocks do you want to mine?: ")
```

but if you want a fancy pop-up window to appear asking you for the number of blocks or basically anything you could do that with the tkinter library:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog

def get_user_input():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    user_input = simpledialog.askstring("Input", "Number of blocks you want to mine:")
    return user_input

value = get_user_input()
print("Blocks the user want to mine:", value)
```